# Android How to implement AsyncTask in my custom Listview

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-asynctask, custom-lists

When I ran my code I always get a log about `Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` How to implement AsyncTask in this code below, and how to show a progressbar, while fetching data from one of my Parse.com's database. I would appreciate any help.

---

Here is my Activity's code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctors_name_list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String key = extras.getString("KEY");
    ListView lvDoctorsName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDoctorsName);

    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("doctors");
            query.whereContains("name", key);
            return query;
        }
    };
    CustomLayout urgentAdapter = new CustomLayout(this, factory);
    lvDoctorsName.setAdapter(urgentAdapter);

    TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_list_item);
    lvDoctorsName.setEmptyView(empty);

    itemClickListener();
}

public void itemClickListener() {
    ListView lvDoctorsName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDoctorsName);
    lvDoctorsName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ParseObject item = (ParseObject) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            String objectID = item.getObjectId().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DoctorPage.class);
            //i.putExtra("new_variable_name",value);
            i.putExtra("objectID", objectID);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

And here my custom layout:

```
public class CustomLayout extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {


public CustomLayout(Context context, QueryFactory<ParseObject> queryFactory) {
    super(context, queryFactory);
}


@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.row, null);
    }
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("name"));

    TextView titleTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    titleTextView2.setText(object.getString("city"));

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see is that you are calling `findViewById()` every time `getItemView()` is called; `findViewById()` is an expensive operation. You should implement something like the [`ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) pattern to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you @Emmanuel. But it still shows that: Skipped 319 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. It is really slow when I press the back button, to go back for the previous Activity.

Comment: You may want to look at other parts of your app as well.

Comment: this does not answer the question being asked, i guess that is why you were downvoted

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the Parse documentation they take care of the `AsyncTask` for you. So that's not the problem.

Depending on the size of your data set, Emmanuel's answer with `findViewById` is correct.

To answer how to show a progress bar you can read the documentation on the `ParseQueryAdapter`, which lets you hook into loading / done loading triggers.

https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html

```
// Perhaps set a callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
  public void onLoading() {
    // Trigger any "loading" UI
  }

  public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
    // Execute any post-loading logic, hide "loading" UI
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @jlindenbaum I am gonne check that. But currently my database just consists of 5 rows and 5 coloums, so it is not huge. There is not to much data set.

Comment: Have you found anything causing the skipped frames? You can look into CPU usage.

Comment: I tried it on my tablet and it works fine, it shows just 30-60 skipped frames in logcat. So it is highly depends on the device permofmarnce?

Comment: It does. But from your code and your tiny data set there's nothing that looks like it should be working that hard.